# bind9 takes a long time before forwarding a query

Tags: bind

tcpdump says:

```
1619344994.943919 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 39270, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 54)
    10.107.2.10.52446 > 10.107.3.4.53: [udp sum ok] 7139+ A? censored.de. (26)
1619344997.346817 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14567, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 77)
    10.107.3.4.51969 > 192.109.102.65.53: [udp sum ok] 14985 [1au] A? censored.de. ar: . OPT UDPsize=512 DO (49)
[ fast response+reply skipped because not relevant ]
```

I do not understand why bind needs more than two seconds to decide where to forward this request. The machine is otherwise not loaded, there is only one network interface, no IP filters, no checksum errors or whatever, no forwarders, no special config for this zone (also, the problem randomly affects other zones).

192.109.102.65 is a NS for the domain in question. I see no requests to the "de" zone servers requesting NS records (or anything else for that matter) for this zone. Any follow-up request is answered instantly from cache.

Any ideas what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: NB: Downvoting a question is all well and good but IMHO somewhat stupid if you don't leave a comment stating *why you did it*. *Sigh*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet would be that it tries to reach the NS via IPv6, which fails in a way that isn't detected by bind (e.g. a default-DROP firefall rule), so it waits for the timeout and then falls back to the next server, which happens to be the v4 address.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; the actual reason was that the IPv6 route pointed to a host that refused to reply to ARP (OK, neighbor discovery …).